# Origin point of application insights data in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have enabled application insights on a couple of web service end points. Is there a way to check which end point the application insights log data comes from? Thank you.

Comment: If you go to Application Insights blade of your web service, and view the `Transaction Search`, you will see the full URL for which the HTTP requests are coming in. Can you share what you find and more details of your app service.

Comment: It'd be useful to know in more detail what you want to see.

Comment: In the logs blade, you can query the items with filter conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used url as filter in order to filter the query from the logs. Here is my query

```
requests  
|where url contains "https://webapp12408.azurewebsites.net"
```

[image]

[image]